# What is the best way of removing last character of string in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I use the following, but is there any easy way for doing this ?

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'uk,usa,germany,poland,';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@x,0, LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@x)) + 1);
```

the output is :

```
uk,usa,germany,poland
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even better would be to figure out to avoid using delimited strings in sql in the first place.

Comment: I agree with [the above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111233/what-is-the-best-way-of-removing-last-character-of-string-in-sql#comment44597107_28111233); bring your database into [1NF (first normal form)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and you won't have to face this issue at all.

Comment: In fact, @x is a result of query. I am using "for xml path" in subquery and concat contries with comma . At UI, I dont want to display last comma in countries, so for this I am trying to do this in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select left(@x, len(@x) - 1)
```

Note that LEN does not include trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using STUFF:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'uk,usa,germany,poland,';
select STUFF(@x,LEN(@x),1,' ')
```

Comment: Wouldn't select STUFF(@x,LEN(@x),1,' ') be better ?

Comment: STUFF and FOR XML PATH is a good combination. I' ll try this. Thanks

Comment: @onur : Accept or Upvote if u found it as your desired solution...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid errors on empty strings, I suggest using SUBSTRING starting from character position 0 instead of LEFT. Using left with my test data would fail.

```
DECLARE @t table(col1 varchar(20))
INSERT @t values('abc,'),(''), ('Denmark,')

SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(col1, 0, len(col1)) 
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
abc
<empty row>
Denmark
```